# Existence of a (m+1)-dimensional cylinder inside a (m+1) open ball

Tags: general-topology, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was studying the proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODE.

At the beginning there is this statement:

given that A is an open set in $R^{m+1}$, we know that there will exist and (m+1)-dimensional cylinder (closed) with center in $(x_0,\mathbf{u}_0)$ all included in the set A.

$
R={(x,\mathbf{u})\in R^{m+1}:|x-x_0|\le a, |\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{u}_0|\le b}
$

Are we sure it exist? How can we prove it ?

Comment: What do you know from "$A$ is an open set" and "$(x_0,u_0)$ is an inner point of $A$"?

Comment: @LutzL I know that there is a ball all included in A. So there is also a cylinder inscribed in this ball. I know this. I was wondering if there was a more formal proof of that

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$If $a$, $b$, and $R$ are positive real numbers such that $a^{2} + b^{2} < R^{2}$, then the cylinder
$$
\{(x, \Vec{u}) \in \Reals \times \Reals^{n} : |x - x_{0}| \leq a,\ \|\Vec{u} - \Vec{u}_{0}\| \leq b\}
$$
(i.e., the product of the interval $[x_{0} - a, x_{0} + a]$ and the closed $n$-ball of radius $b$ centered at $\Vec{u}_{0}$) is contained in the open $(n + 1)$-ball of radius $R$ centered at $(x_{0}, \Vec{u}_{0})$.